# How do I add colored corners to a background image?

Tags: html, css, layout

Is it possible to design what is shown in image using only html and css?

If yes, how?

If No, what is the alternative?

creating transparent image with 2  colored corners and applying it as background image to div that holds text is in my mind. Is there any better way to do this?

I like to do it using html and css only because then it becomes flexible than using image.

I added the code that i  tried. please check. got the desired output. but i would like to know if any improvements can be made ?

[image]

```
<style>
#rules
{
     width:200px;
     height:100px;
}
#rules .top, #rules .bottom
{
    width:200px;
    height:10px;
    float:left;
}
#rules .top::before
{
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    width:40px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:#000;
}
#rules .left, #rules .right
{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    height:30px;
}

#rules .left::before
{
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    width:10px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#000;
}
.center
{
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
#rules .right::after
{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    width:10px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#000;
    float:right;
}
#rules .bottom::after
{
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    width:40px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:#000;
    float:right;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="rules">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="left"></div> 
    <div class="center">RULES</div> 
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>         
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes...now off you go.

Comment: oh dear! down voted twice

Comment: you can do it with help of empty div's

Comment: You've been downvoted because you didn't show existing code like the one for your proposed solution. OK at least you proposed something so that's not the "do it for me asap" question ;) but that doesn't seem sufficient (and isn't)

Comment: What ideas do you have to get started?

Comment: +1 for adding code you've tried to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I'd achieve this effect using psuedo-elements. Use `::before` and `::after` for each of the corners, and use their left and top (respectively right and bottom) borders in the colour you want. You can then set their width and height. Be sure to set the "hidden" borders to zero width so that you don't get slanted corners.

If you have a problem implementing this, please feel free to come back with the code you have tried :)

Comment: Thank you soo much for ur reply and thanks for being kind on me when some of them have down voted this. i didin't know about pseudo elements. so it was diffficult. I tried ::after and ::before and got the output. check my code and tell whether any improvements can be made.

Comment: You seem to have missed the point of psuedo-elements. You should be able to accomplish the layout using ONLY `<div id="rules">RULES</div>`. Certainly, 10 out of 10 for trying, and you *did* achieve the effect, however it is very inefficient and bloated.

Comment: I'm going to leave the solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9aACc/) for you, but I would suggest giving it a thorogh try yourself before looking at it, okay? That's the best way to learn :)

Comment: @KrishGowda I'm a little worried that you think you connected being downvoted to not "being kind". On StackOverflow, they are definitely two different things. I've seen people leave some very nasty comments (which are very quickly removed), and I've seen questions downvoted many times with almost no comments. Downvoting means "This question doesn't show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." It doesn't mean people are being mean; in your case, it just indicates that either the question asker didn't provide enough information. Later, you edited your question and included the css.

Comment: @KrishGowda I'm willing to bet that if you had put your css into the question from the beginning, you wouldn't have been downvoted at all. In fact, I most likely would have upvoted the question (note, that I didn't downvote you... I simply didn't vote at all.) One last comment: I sincerely hope that you come back to StackOverflow, because you've shown that you CAN write good questions, as long as you consider "what other pieces of information are people going to want?" (sample code, exact error message, expected vs. actual behavior). Include those in your question. Good luck in the future.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Makes a good point. In fact, I've upvoted you and kinda wish I could do so twice because you took what I gave you and gave it a genuine try.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol +1 Almost forgot you.. nice answer!

Comment: @LynnCrumbling That's not true... i only meant that Niet was kind enough to answer even though my question did not follow the stackoverflow standards... he had 2 options...  practically, i did learn something from Niet and from the others... i did not oppose the act of downvoting but i did rate Niet's action above it...

Comment: @LynnCrumbling and it was very nice of u for writing those words to me. thank you..